# Dynamically loading _any_ assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-8.0, libgit2sharp, dynamic-loading

... where by *any* assembly I mean also assemblies that depend on assemblies which are wrappers of native libraries.

The [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this question is here:

https://gitlab.com/mikenakis-public/dotnet/playground/loadingnativelibraries

I have a library called `MyLib`. It exports `MyType`, which contains one method: `void DoYourThing()`. This method uses some type from the `LibGit2Sharp` package, so for this reason, `MyLib.csproj` contains `<PackageReference Include="LibGit2Sharp" Version="0.29.0" />`.  Not that it matters, but here is the code:

```
public static void DoYourThing()
{
    string currentDirectory = SysIo.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    Sys.Console.WriteLine( $"Current Directory: {currentDirectory}" );
    string repositoryDirectory = LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Discover( currentDirectory );
    Sys.Console.WriteLine( $"Repository Directory: {repositoryDirectory}" );
    bool valid = LibGit2Sharp.Repository.IsValid( repositoryDirectory );
    Sys.Console.WriteLine( $"Is a valid repository: {valid.ToString().ToUpperInvariant()}" );
}
```

It just so happens that the `LibGit2Sharp` package is a managed wrapper around a native library, but I have no say on this and no control over this, and I would like my code to not have the slightest knowledge of this.

Then I have an application called `DirectDependencyApp` which has a dependency on `MyLib`, and contains the statement `MyType.DoYourThing();`, proving that the whole thing works.

Now, I have an application called `DynamicLoadingApp` which depends on nothing. Instead, it accepts a DLL path-name as a command-line argument, it loads it as an assembly, it finds a type with a `DoYourThing` method, and it invokes that method.  Not that it matters, but here is the code:

```
string assemblyFilePath = SysIo.Path.GetFullPath( arguments.Single() );
SysReflect.Assembly assembly = SysReflect.Assembly.LoadFrom( assemblyFilePath );
SysReflect.MethodInfo methodInfo = assembly.GetTypes().Single().GetMethod( "DoYourThing" ) ?? throw new Sys.Exception();
methodInfo.Invoke( null, null );
```

(Disclosure: what I am ***actually*** doing is writing a test-runner like **VSTest.Console.exe**: it discovers all projects within a solution that produce VisualStudio-UnitTesting-compatible test assemblies, and runs them. `DynamicLoadingApp` corresponds to the test-runner, `MyLib` corresponds to a test assembly, and `LibGit2Sharp` corresponds to an assembly-under-test, or a library that the assembly-under-test depends on. It is crucial to note that the test-runner wants to know nothing specific about each test assembly, and nothing at all about each assembly-under-test. Furthermore,  the test assemblies ***also*** want to know absolutely nothing about any particular test-runner.)

For `DynamicLoadingApp` to be able to load `MyLib`, I already had to do something that I am not quite happy with: I had to add `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true` to `MyLib.csproj`, or else `DynamicLoadingApp` would fail while trying to load `MyLib` because `LibGit2Sharp.dll` could not be found. I am not happy with this, but let's ignore that for now, it might be the subject of another question. The fact is that by adding `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true` I got past that hurdle. Unfortunately, that's when I arrived at the main hurdle.

When `DynamicLoadingApp` runs, it successfully finds `MyLib`, and it successfully loads it, (which means that `LibGit2Sharp` gets successfully loaded,) and it successfully invokes the `DoYourThing` method, but as soon as the method tries to actually invoke any method of `LibGit2Sharp`, the whole thing blows up with:

```
System.TypeInitializationException:
'The type initializer for 'LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods' threw an exception.'
```

The inner exception is:

```
DllNotFoundException:
Unable to load DLL 'git2-a2bde63' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found.
(0x8007007E)
```

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:

```
LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.InitializeNativeLibrary()
LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.NativeMethods()
```

The call stack shown in Visual Studio is this:

```
LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_repository_discover.AnonymousMethod__0({LibGit2Sharp.Core.Handles.GitBuf})  Unknown
LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.ConvertPath({Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}})   Unknown
LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_repository_discover({LibGit2Sharp.Core.FilePath})   Unknown
LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Discover("D:\\Personal\\LoadingNativeLibraries")    Unknown
MyLib.MyType.DoYourThing()  C#
```

So, what is happening is that `GitLib2Sharp`, which is a library that I have absolutely no control over, is failing to locate its own native libraries. Of course this problem is not specific to `GitLib2Sharp`, it pertains to any wrapper of native libraries.

I know there are workarounds for fixing the problem by copying the native binaries from `bin/Debug/net8.0/runtimes/win-x64` to `bin/Debug/net8.0`, or by using some MSBuild property which will put them directly there, but I want a proper solution so that I can give `DynamicLoadingApp` to people and tell them "here, use it" without having to tell them "before you can use it you have to modify each and every one of your MyLibs to accommodate DynamicLoadingApp's quirks".

So:

How can I get `DynamicLoadingApp` to load `MyLib` and have `MyLib` successfully invoke `Gitlib2Sharp`?

The solution must involve modifications only to `DynamicLoadingApp`. (Not modifications to `MyLib`, which works as it is.)

Comment: Cant you just add the files in the runtimes folder also? So bin/Debug/net8.0 and all sub folder.

Comment: @Magnus I do not understand your question. Add the files where? `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true` in MyLib's project file causes all binaries (including those under `runtimes`) to be emitted into MyLib's `bin` directory.  And although `MyLib` succeeds in loading `GitLib2Sharp` from that `bin` directory, it fails to locate the stuff under `runtimes`.  Plus, I have already stated that I did not really want to be doing even this.  In any case, I added a link to a cloneable MRE, so you can try any idea with it.

Comment: Since it is `MyLib` dependent on `LibGit2Sharp`, how to ensure that `LibGit2Sharp` can be loaded successfully should be a concern for `MyLib` (or for `DirectDependencyApp`). Alternatively, your test runner may accept some search path like options to complete this task.

Comment: @shingo `MyLib` works fine, as `DirectDependencyApp` proves. Things get weird when it is dynamically loaded by `DynamicLoadingApp`, so it is `DynamicLoadingApp` that must take whatever measures are necessary in order to load it properly.

Comment: @shingo it is possible to pass search-path-like options to the test runner, and it is possible to discover those options. My question then is what is the test runner going to do with these options.  How it is going to put them to use.

Comment: Is the problem that it locates dependencies based on the program or working directory, and not the directory for the `assemblyFilePath` ?

Comment: @JonasH I do not know.  If you clone the solution you will see that I tried fiddling around with the working directory, but it did not seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

So, I found the answer. It required creating my own `AssemblyLoadContext` which makes use of an `AssemblyDependencyResolver`. Here is the full code:

```
namespace DynamicLoadingApp;

using System.Linq;
using SysLoader = System.Runtime.Loader;
using Sys = System;
using SysIo = System.IO;
using SysReflect = System.Reflection;

sealed class DynamicLoadingAppMain
{
    static void Main( string[] arguments )
    {
        Sys.Console.WriteLine( nameof( DynamicLoadingAppMain ) );
        string assemblyFilePath = SysIo.Path.GetFullPath( arguments.Single() );
        SysLoader.AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext = new ResolvingAssemblyLoadContext( assemblyFilePath );
        SysReflect.Assembly assembly = assemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath( assemblyFilePath );
        SysReflect.MethodInfo methodInfo = assembly.GetTypes().Single().GetMethod( "DoYourThing" ) ?? throw new Sys.Exception();
        methodInfo.Invoke( null, null );
        Sys.Console.Write( "Press [Enter] to continue: " );
        Sys.Console.ReadLine();
    }

    sealed class ResolvingAssemblyLoadContext : SysLoader.AssemblyLoadContext
    {
        readonly SysLoader.AssemblyDependencyResolver resolver;

        public ResolvingAssemblyLoadContext( string assemblyFilePath )
        {
            resolver = new SysLoader.AssemblyDependencyResolver( assemblyFilePath );
        }

        protected override SysReflect.Assembly? Load( SysReflect.AssemblyName assemblyName )
        {
            string? assemblyPath = resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath( assemblyName );
            if( assemblyPath != null )
                return LoadFromAssemblyPath( assemblyPath );
            return null;
        }

        protected override nint LoadUnmanagedDll( string unmanagedDllName )
        {
            string? libraryPath = resolver.ResolveUnmanagedDllToPath( unmanagedDllName );
            if( libraryPath != null )
                return LoadUnmanagedDllFromPath( libraryPath );
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the (glorious!) output:

```
DynamicLoadingAppMain
Current Directory: D:\Personal\LoadingNativeLibraries
Repository Directory: D:\Personal\LoadingNativeLibraries\.git\
Is a valid repository: TRUE
Press [Enter] to continue:
```